# Problem aligning flex items in a row inside a flex-contianer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

everyone. I found this code at Frontend Mentor. It is part of a challenge, so I have to edit it until it looks like the finished image. I'm not that faraway, I just don't know how to make the div elements inside the div belonging to the card-stadistics class display inside a row instead of a column. Here you have the html and css code.

https://codepen.io/jonanaff/pen/wvJBxrG

Here's is the finished image.

[Finished projetct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kisem.jpg)

This is where I'm currently at.

[Where I'm currently at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AON99.png)

I've tried using

```
.card-stadistics {
display: inline-flex;
```

}

instead of

```
.card-stadistics {
display: inline-flex;
```

}

and I've also tried to apply the flex-basis property to the .card-stadistics class, but without any success.

My guess is that the problem has more to do with the dimensions of the elements than the properties that are being used, but I don't know how to tackle it. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your class.

Change

```
<div class="card-stadisticts">
```

to

```
<div class="card-stadistics">
```

It's working fine here:

```css
    body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}


.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: hsl(185,75%,39%);
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jorsuap/profile-card-component-main/2f7472b48e4faab249c24e93960228dc4a6cd578/images/bg-pattern-top.svg), url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jorsuap/profile-card-component-main/2f7472b48e4faab249c24e93960228dc4a6cd578/images/bg-pattern-bottom.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% -430px, 100% 450px;
}

.container-card {
    width: 350px;
    height: 380px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px hsl(185,75%,28%);
    z-index: 2;
}

#pattern-card {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

#img-perfil {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 3px white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 43%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.card-information {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 150px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px rgb(194, 192, 192);
}


h3 {
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


p {
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 59%);
} 


span {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 59%);
}


.card-stadistics {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0 30px;
}


.card-stadistics div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column; 
    flex-basis: 10px;
}

h3 {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="container-card">
            <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jorsuap/profile-card-component-main/2f7472b48e4faab249c24e93960228dc4a6cd578/images/bg-pattern-card.svg" alt="banner" id="pattern-card">
            <img src="https://github.com/jorsuap/profile-card-component-main/blob/main/images/image-victor.jpg?raw=true" alt="img-perfil" id="img-perfil">
            <div class="card-information">
                <h3> Victor Crest <span>26</span></h3>
                <p>London</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-stadistics">
                <div>
                    <h3>80K</h3>
                    <p>Followers</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>803K</h3>
                    <p>Likes</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>1.4K</h3>
                    <p>Photos</p>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Of course, thank you! I will be more careful with this silly details next time.